# Calculate factorial by using mips

Tags: recursion, mips, factorial

The contents from the attached picture really confuse me. In my understanding, when executing the command the given command  "beq $t0,$zero,L1", it will jump to label L1, However, when executing the command "jal fact"  it will jump back to the label fact and repeat the same operation over and over again.  In this case, the commands after "jal fact" would not be executed. So, what's wrong with my understanding
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsgFY.png)

Comment: _"In this case, the commands after "jal fact" would not be executed"_. Sure they will; at some point there will be a return from that particular call (typically, unless you have a bug).

Comment: You know you can run that code in a simulator, right?  Try it on a very small input, such as fact(2).  But maybe first, study recursion in C, because it works the same: a function calls itself to solve a smaller problem, then builds the next solution when the smaller problem has been solved.

Comment: Let's also note that the `beq` that you've cited is a *conditional* branch.  Thus, it will *sometimes* branch to the label `L1`, but sometime not branch...